# How does git store the "edges" in the graph of commits?

Tags: git

I understand that all a branch is in git is a sort of pointer to a commit.  When you `git checkout` a branch, the commit is fetched and git traverses the graph all the way back to the beginning of the repo in order to put the appropriate content into the working directory.

I also understand that a commit is a combination of three pieces of information: the author, the timestamp, and the contents of all files that are modified by the commit.

My question is this: given that a branch is a pointer to a commit, how does the commit refer to its predecessor commit(s)?  Are these pointers part of the commit itself, or is it part of some other data structure?

Comment: The book describes it very well: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A commit is actually a collection of at least:

- Author
- Committer
- Date
- Comment
- SHA1 of the tree (directory content)
- SHA1 of the parent commits. There can be 0 to N parents.

(The ID of the commit itself is not actually stored within it, but it is instead the hash (SHA1) all these fields.)

As you can see a commit contains all the IDs of its parents, so that's where the edges of the DAG lie.

Note that, although a commit usually has one parent, there can be a commit with no parents (the very first commit in a project) and also there can be a commit with several parents (a merge commit).

Comment: When you say the SHA1 of the parent commits, you mean the has that appears as `commit xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` when you type `git log`?

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon: Yes, in git every object is identified by the hash of its contents, which is a 20 byte value, usually shown as a 40 digit hexadecimal value, as in `git log`, although sometimes only the first few digits are shown, as in `git reflog`.

Answer (score 1):

The `commit` objects reference their parents.
Try e.g.:

```
git cat-file -p HEAD
```

in a repo to see what a commit object looks like.

---

(
In my latest project I get:

```
tree 57e0841e4adc30ff92621e6b60e9dd101f667ba4
parent 54f9dba66b49e0040e2190d94db0fe02a29601be
author Petr Skocik <pskocik@gmail.com> 1448749832 +0100
committer Petr Skocik <pskocik@gmail.com> 1448750602 +0100
```

As you can see, the commit object mentions the parent (or parents).
)

Comment: I highly recommend to use `git cat-file -p` starting from the sha1 of a commit and ending to blobs to see how git store it's data. Give it a 5 minutes try and you will understand git better!